# Good practice to move users mouse to ok/cancel buttons?

Tags: button, mouseevent

Is it considered good practice to move the users mouse?

For example, in an installer, moving it to the `next` or `agree` buttons. Or in VLC's case, moving it to the `cancel` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise not since the user might click an unwanted button. I've never seen this kind of UX in commercial softwares.

Usually, softwares will offer the user to trigger a button with a keyboard combination starting with Alt (e.g. "Alt + O" for OK). Usually, when the user presses Alt, the O of OK will be underlined to suggest that such a feature exists. [This is often implementable implicitly as a Mnemonic in the dialog's engine (e.g. Java Swing).](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/setting-shortcut-key-and-hotkey-for-menu-item-and-button-in-swing)